# Template pattern in Jersey?

Tags: design-patterns, jersey

I am creating RESTful webservices using Jersey 2.10.1. I want to have a base class which will have a central place for creating some IDs which I will propagate throughout the application. This base class will also have a try catch block where any exception generated in the child classes will be caught. I would like to know if this base class should extend the ServletContainer ? I am trying to develop a template pattern. My base class would get called which would then delegate the calls to child classes. Is there any better or alternate way of doing this ? I would appreciate any suggestions or tips.

```
public class BaseClass extends ServletContainer {

  public Value<Integer> service(URI baseUri, URI requestUri,
                               final HttpServletRequest request,
                                HttpServletResponse response) throws          ServletException,IOException {
        1. GENERATE UNIQUE ID
          try { 
          return webComponent.service(baseUri, requestUri, request, response);
         } catch(Throwable e) {
              //LOG the exception here
           }
    }
}

@Path("/test")
public class Child extends BaseClass {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make abstract BaseClass and create an abstract method `generateId`. The childs must implement it. In `service` method of the BaseClass, first call `generateId()` and it will call the concrete implementation of each child.